# How to avoid orphan rules for repr transparent wrappers

Tags: rust

My problem is I want to have a transparent wrapper and implemented `Into<underlying>` for it. Unfortunately, rust's orphan rules forbid it. Here is a simple example:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct MyWrapper<T>(pub T);

impl<T> Into<T> for MyWrapper<T> {
    fn into(self) -> T {
        self.0
    }
}
```

The question is is there any way I can implement it? I'm using macro to generate impl for all types I'm currently using but it looks very awkward and dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the Deref trait instead. The Deref docs contain the following [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#examples) which is almost identical to your code:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

struct DerefExample<T> {
    value: T
}

impl<T> Deref for DerefExample<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = DerefExample { value: 'a' };
    assert_eq!('a', *x);
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't allow to own the value but maybe it's good enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in a regular impl block:

```
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct MyWrapper<T>(pub T);

impl<T> MyWrapper<T> {
    pub fn into(self) -> T {
        self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let wrapped : MyWrapper<f32> = MyWrapper::<f32>(3.4f32);
    let unwrapped : f32 = wrapped.into();
    println!("{}", unwrapped);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work for most cases. It's not really different from `.0`, the reason you may want to use `into` is using it in functions like `foo<T: Into<MyStruct>>` which can't be done without implementing a trait